# Cast JSON object (NSCFDictionary) to string and parse it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json

I'm working with facebook connect and trying to handle the JSON object that i'm receiving.
I invoked the requstWithGraphPath method and need to get back a JSON object,
tried to parse it and getting an error:

```
SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:result];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; -> in this line - "[__NSCFDictionary length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"
NSArray *events = [parser objectWithString:jsonString];
```

What's the problem?
Can I get the string in an other way or parse the object differently?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with the delegate callback

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result;
```

the parsing work has been done for you. Traverse the NSDictionary or NSArray to find the data you are looking for. If you are working with the delegate callback

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoadRawResponse:(NSData *)data;
```

you should initialize an NSString with the data, and use the category method that SBJSON adds to NSString for creating an id. That is assuming the data is data that constructs a string.

```
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
id result = [jsonString JSONValue];
```

Comment: JSONValue is, or at least was at the time, a category method added by SBJSON.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the error happens on that line, or does it happen on the line above?

If `result` is an `NSDictionary` (or `CFDictionary`, same thing), then it is already parsed and you do not need to do that yourself — and it could cause that error message too, on the line above.

The line:

```
data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:result];
```

is almost certainly not what you want to do, as it is equivalent to

```
data = [result copy];
```

assuming that `result` is an `NSData` object (or `NSMutableData`), which I'm guessing it isn't.